# Bootstrap: search visible when navbar collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have my search bar visible when the navbar collapses.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/edalzell/a3yng825/1/ works when collapsed but shows two search bars when expanded.

[image: Two search bars]

HTML:

```
<header class= "blog-masthead">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <form class="navbar-form collapsed navbar-right" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch" name="query">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>

                </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch" name="query">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: For future readers using Bootstrap 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-items-to-the-right/41513784#41513784

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you have two search bars declared,you have a couple of options to get the desired result

1. Remove the extra searchbar that you have declared in the collapse
   section
2. Hide/show specific items on your desired resolution ,you can check
   [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207109/hiding-elements-in-responsive-layout)

I have used the first way ,you can find the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3yng825/2/)

Complete code:

```
<header class= "blog-masthead">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <form class="navbar-form collapsed navbar-right" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch" name="query">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: that's great, but I want the search bar on the right when expanded, not the left. That's why I tried it with two. Any suggestions?

Comment: visible-xs works fine with two search forms so I will go with that right now, unless I can figure out how to just have one of them!