# hiding display using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the below code for display in different ways in mobile and desktop. but both the sentences are displaying at the same time.

```
<div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-lg hidden-sm visible-md">  
        Page-under-Construction.Please-try-again-later.  
    </div>  
    <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs">  
        Page-under-Construction.  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the other two answers:

- Do only use hidden or visible on a single element (as mentioned)
- Be aware that visible-* is deprecated now. Instead, there should be a display property at the end. An example is visible-md-block . See this thread: [Hiding elements in responsive layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207109/hiding-elements-in-responsive-layout)

Here's a plunker using the code you provided: http://plnkr.co/edit/brjPCsh578WGu5Eq1rWl?p=preview

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    Page-under-Construction. Please-try-again later.
</div>  
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">  
    Page-under-Construction.  
</div>
```

Comment: do I need to change any settings in browser,for this purpose?bcz, the code works fine in plunker...but not in firefox in my system

Comment: No problem. To be clear, visible itself is not deprecated, just without a display property at the end. The thread I mentioned has a thorough explanation.

Comment: @suryababy No, you shouldn't need to change a setting in your browser. My guess would be an issue with load order or having an older version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Use either hidden or visible (try not to use visible, see below), not both in the same class

[Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm)

```
<div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">  
    Page-under-Construction.Please-try-again-later.  
</div>  
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">  
    Page-under-Construction.  
</div>
```

edited:  as pointed out below "visible" is now deprecated (see Drew Thomas' answer for explaination)

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/2wzyvLv5/)

Also check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) documentation from Twitter Bootstrap.

Visible to mobile only :

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    Content to show in mobile  
</div>
```

Hidden to mobile only :

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    Content to show in mobile  
</div>
```