# Do no use a property on mobile / bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As mentionned, I would like to not have a property on a div on mobile device.

I have done that so far, which works with chrome but probably not with other browsers :

```
 <div collapse="true" class="visible-xs">
 <div class="hidden-xs">
    ...
 </div>
```

What's the correct way to do this ? Is there a way I can get away without using js ?

Thanks

Comment: This code makes no sense. You're only showing the containing element on mobile, but then you're hiding the child element on mobile, so nothing will be visible at any size.

Comment: Please clarify the question

Comment: Please check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207109/hiding-elements-in-responsive-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'not have a property on a div', do you mean how to hide a div on a mobile device? If so the second div in the snippet should work cross-browser thanks to the class="hidden-xs".

The first div in the snippet will only be shown on devices with viewports which fall within the xs range (<768px based on an unmodified build of Bootstrap 3).

Using what you've written would show the user separate content based on the device's viewport size.