# How to remove an html <table> column using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have an HTML `<table>` with many columns, so when my web page is displayed on a mobile browser, it's too small. So I'm creating a media query and I want to remove some columns (That are not important).

So how to remove an html column using only css ?

For example, how to remove the column "B" in the middle of the table on the next example :

```css
table, th, td, tr{
  border:1px solid black;
}

table{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>

<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use `display: none;`

Comment: The answers are good. But I would recommend you [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). That is the way you have to deal with such problems actually in web development. It is crossbrowser safe and has many adventages.

Answer (score 6):

```
<style>
        table, th, td, tr{
  border:1px solid black;
}

table{
  width:100%;
}

  @media (max-width: 768px){

    tr th:nth-child(2),tr td:nth-child(2){

      display:none;
    }

  }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not what you asked for, but how about making the table horizontally scrollable?

The scrollbar will only appear when the window cannot fit the content if you use `overflow-x: auto`.

```css
table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.hscroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.example {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="hscroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td class="example">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: A much better idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use n-th child to manage table columns.

```
th:nth-child(2) { display:none; }
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest aginst this as it will break as soon as you use colspan.
Also, if you do this, don't forget to hide the regular colums. `tr > td:nth-child(2) { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use css [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and inside media query write styles for hiding columns:

```css
table, th, td, tr{
  border:1px solid black;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px){
  table tr th:nth-child(2),
  table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use nth-child, it will cause issues later when you add/remove more th/td's. Better use a class which you can reuse in your entire application.

---

```
<table>
<th>A</th>
<th class="hide-on-mobile">B</th>
<th>C</th>

<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="hide-on-mobile">Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td class="hide-on-mobile">Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

@media (max-width: 768px){
    hide-on-mobile{
      display:none;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is using `col` elements with `visibility: collapse`.

```html
<colgroup>
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
</colgroup>
```

```css
col:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```css
table, th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
col:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way will work properly even if you use `colspan`.

However, note the layout of the table will be calculated before hiding the columns. And at the end, the remaining columns won't grow to make the table respect `width: 100%`. As described in [Dynamic effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#dynamic-effects), this avoids expensive re-layout operations. To compensate this, you can increase the width of the table beyond `100%`.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
table, th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.grow {
  width: 150%;
}
col.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Full table
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">A B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Eve Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  Hiding last column
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col class="hidden" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">A B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Eve Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  Hiding last column and enlarging table
  <table class="grow">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col class="hidden" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">A B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Eve Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the second column:

```
table tr>th:nth-of-type(2),   table tr>td:nth-of-type(2){
    display: none;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 900px){ /* use your media breakpoint */
  table tr>th:nth-of-type(2),   table tr>td:nth-of-type(2){
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th id="foo">B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k81rumy/)

**Note**: your HTML is not valid - `th` must also be inside the `tr` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use html tables I would recommend using stacktable.js.  Otherwise use css display tables.

Answer (score -2):

Since everyone goes straight forward, I would like to recommend you **[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** - this would help you in many situations when dealing with responsive design. After installing it, you will have to modify your code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can read more about it at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207109/hiding-elements-in-responsive-layout).

Comment: Who down voted this answer? What is wrong with it? Idiot behavior?