# Using python / Jupyter Notebook, how to prevent row numbers from printing?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I print a database, it prints with row numbers. In spyder, I use print(df), while in jupyter notebook, I am using df to print. Any suggestions?

```
        brand         mean_price  mean_mileage(km)  total_listed 
 0      volkswagen    3913        140769            8046
 1      opel          2697        138046            4065
 2      bmw           5313        143804            4048
 3      mercedes_benz 4790        143507            3526
 4      audi          5221        144614            3031
 5      ford          2912        136321            2483
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this?

Comment: No particular reason except my curiosity in learning more coding as I work towards Data Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep something similar to dataframe formatting as you expressed in a comment to @Prachiti, would be assign another column to be the index. For example, you could make brand the `index` with the following:

```py
df = df.set_index('brand')
```

Alternatively, display it as HTML.
The simplest aproach is to remove the index column when doing the conversion to HTML, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722065/8508004). It will display like a dataframe.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html(index=False))
```

However, it is even possible just to combine with CSS to display the HTML table in similar style as dataframe rendering while using `display:none;` to hide the first column.

The code in total would be as shown below; however, you could break it into as many cells as desired:

```py
html=df.to_html()
# css modified from cell #9  https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fomightez/dataframe2img/blob/master/index.ipynb
# and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811124/8508004
css = """
<style type=\"text/css\">
table {
color: #333;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 340px;
border-collapse:
collapse; 
border-spacing: 0;
}
td, th {
border: 1px solid transparent; /* No more visible border */
font-size: 12.8px;
height: 24px;
}
th {
background: #FAFAFA; /* Darken header a bit */
font-weight: bold;
}
td {
background: #FAFAFA;
text-align: center;
font-size: 11.8px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
background-color: white;
}
th:nth-child(1) { display:none; }
</style>
"""
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(css+html)
```

Here is an image showing the result with an example dataframe (code in first cell [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fomightez/dataframe2img/blob/master/index.ipynb)):
[image]

Comment: Your simple code of set_index worked, except the headings got split in two lines and 'Brand' is in the second line. Like in your example, 'Item' and 'In_stock' would be on line 1 and 'Manufacturer' on line 2, but above their respective columns

Comment: Yes, the index won't show quite on same line as other columns; however, I added a way that doesn't involve needing CSS, too.

Comment: It worked great!  Yet to learn on bringing HTML/CSS into python

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
print (df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: the table boundaries are not displayed anymore in jupyter notebook